# Symfony 5.3 : Assign User to Object with JWT

Tags: jwt, api-platform.com, symfony5, lexikjwtauthbundle

I'm working with Api-platform and I tried to inject my user authenticated in object, for a post request.

My problem is, when send my user in object:

```
obj->setUser($this->security->getUser());
```

I need a password and I have a error:

```
An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Le champ 'password' ne peut être vide (null)
```

I authenticated my user with a JWT Token and I create my user in `createFromPayload()` (JWTUserInterface)

```
public static function createFromPayload($username, array $payload)
{

    $user = new User();

    $user->setId($username)->setEmail($payload['username'] ?? '');
    $user->setRoles($payload['roles']);

    return $user;
}
```

I debug my User object and it's logic my password is null, but how assign my user in my object if password is null?

```
^ App\Entity\User {#13193
  -id: 8
  -email: "test@test.fr"
  -roles: array:1 [
    0 => "ROLE_USER"
  ]
  -password: null
  -wallets: Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection {#13417
    -elements: []
  }
}
```

My class : UserOwnedDenormalizer

```
class UserOwnedDenormalizer implements ContextAwareDenormalizerInterface, DenormalizerAwareInterface
{

    use DenormalizerAwareTrait;


    private const ALREADY_CALLED_DENORMALIZE = 'UserOwnedDenormalizer';

    public function __construct(private UserRepository $userRepository, private Security $security)
    {
    }

    public function supportsDenormalization($data, string $type, ?string $format = null, array $context = [])
    {
        $reflectionClass = new \ReflectionClass($type);

        $alreadyCalled = $context[self::ALREADY_CALLED_DENORMALIZE] ?? false;

        return $reflectionClass->implementsInterface(UserOwnedInterface::class) && $alreadyCalled === false;
    }

    public function denormalize($data, string $type, ?string $format = null, array $context = [])
    {
        $context[self::ALREADY_CALLED_DENORMALIZE] = true;
        
        /** @var UserOwnedInterface $obj */
        $obj = $this->denormalizer->denormalize($data, $type, $format, $context);
   

        $obj->setUser($this->security->getUser());

            
        return $obj;
    }
}
```

My objective is to assign to user in object without passing by Doctrine and my Database.